# Hilbert Schmidt Integral operator with matrix valued kernel

Tags: integration, operator-theory

Im working through Gelfands Rep. Theory of Autom. Func. and I am stuck to show that some operator is trace class. I think it all boils down to the fact that we deal with an integral operator with matrix kernel. In the one dimensional case if we have a Hilbert Schmidt integral operator $L_kf(x)=\int_X k(x,y)f(y) dx $ on $L_2(X)$ where $X$ is compact with continuous kernel $k(x,y)$ then we know it is Hilbert Schmidt with $||L_k||_{HS}=||k||_2^2$. One can use this to show that the operator $L_kL_k^*$ is trace class with trace $\int_X K(x,x) dx$, where $K$ is the continuous kernel of $L_kL_k^*$.
Is there some analogous theory if $k$ is matrix valued and we deal with functions with values in a finite vector space $V$? On a similar note, do we have an $L_2$- or $L_p$- space of matrix valued functions? I would like to do a similar calculation to show that in the matrix case we have $Tr(T_kT_k^*)=\int_X Tr(K(x,x)) dx$ where we have the same assumtions on $X$ and $k$ as above.